# Nginx: access upstream response header in the mirror block

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

My mirroring works just fine, and I am correctly getting the original request body in the mirror server.

However I need to access a response header called `Location` from the original upstream and forward it to my mirror. Typically the response header from upstream will be accessed using this variable: `$upstream_http_<*header name*>`, in my case `$upstream_http_location`.

However I want to access this in my mirror so I can forward the response header from my upstream to my mirror.

How do I do this? Here's my current configuration, but it doesn't work and I don't see the header  `DAV-response` in my mirror.  Is there another way to access all `$upstream_http` headers in the mirror block?

I have the following request mirroring setup in nginx:

```
location /ops/opendata/DataAccessViewer/ {
  mirror /davmirror;
  proxy_pass  https://<upstream>/;
  proxy_redirect  https://<upstream>/ /; 
}

location /davmirror {
    internal;
    proxy_pass https://<mirror>;
    proxy_set_header DAV-Original-URI $request_uri;  # <<<<-- works!
    proxy_set_header DAV-tier internals; # <<<<-- works!
    proxy_set_header DAV-response $upstream_http_location; # <<<-- DOESNT WORK!
}
```

> Update

Open to alternative solutions to achieve this using nginx. I am aware of other non-nginx workarounds and in-fact using those as fallbacks at the moment. Ideally we would want this to be nginx solution.

> Update
> This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51644141/how-to-make-nginx-mirror-module-not-wait-for-response) seems to suggest that nginx is actually waiting on upstream response before resolving mirror?

> Update

Verified that upstream does actually include a 'Location' Header:

[image]

Here's all the headers I receive in the mirror. Note that `DAV-response` is missing

[image]

Comment: is it even possible? Mirror is for mirroring request and doesn't do anything for responses. $upstream_http_* is for headers which are set by upstream response. when You are mirroring the request how do you want to add a header from response which is not available.

Comment: is it possible is actually a valid question I am looking an answer for. Certain variables such as $request_uri are available, so if there's a way to make the mirror wait for a upstream response, then in theory reading upstream response headers should be possible. So looking for any possible solutions from more experienced folks.

Comment: @YaserKalali check this question pls: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51644141/how-to-make-nginx-mirror-module-not-wait-for-response

Seems to suggest nginx does actually wait on the upstream response? Am a interpreting it incorrectly?

Answer (score -1):

Alright, so the issue here is a bit of head-scratcher. You see, Nginx's `mirror` is a bit limited when it comes to waiting for original request to complete. This is probably why `$upstream_http_location` ain't wokring in you'r mirror block.

But hey, there's a workaround you can try, though its not super clean. Have you heard of the `post_action` directive? It's not well documented. But it letys you do stuff after your original `proxy_pass` is done and the response headers are revievd.

Here's how you could tweak your config:

```
location /ops/opendata/DataAccessViewer/ {
  proxy_pass  https://<upstream>/;
  proxy_redirect  https://<upstream>/ /;
  post_action @davmirror;
}

location @davmirror {
  proxy_pass https://<mirror>;
  proxy_set_header DAV-Original-URI $request_uri;
  proxy_set_header DAV-tier internals;
  proxy_set_header DAV-response $upstream_http_location;
}
```

So, `@davmirror`will only kick in after the original `proxy_pass` gets its response. That way, `$upstream_http_location` should be populated and you can forward it to your mirror.

Again, it's not the most elegant solution. If you're looking for something more robust, you might have to go for app-level logic or some custom module.

Comment: Interesting approach! I have been suspecting this is the case of mirror not waiting on upstream response and so it's not reading responses. 
However when I try the post_action like you suggested, nginx now says the the config is invalid: 

`"proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block in /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy/database_services.conf:167`

Any clue how to get around this?

Comment: Do I need to somehow use rewrite now? Sorry not fluent with that config, and appreciate any help